# Cannot access MSSQL using web service(Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver)

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc

I have created a very basic web service using Eclipse to access one of my databases and just run a simple query. When I create the web service in Eclipse and test client, it returns me this exception

```
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

I have already done the following:

1. Use the same code in a different independent Java class and it runs
   fine. The database return results. No Exceptions.
2. I have added the classpath in Eclipse runtime when creating a web service (as I did when I tested step 1 above).

This is the sample code in Eclipse which I wrote and generate the webservice from:

```
    package testservice;
    import java.sql.*;

    import javax.jws.WebService;
    @WebService

    public class testServ {
    public String testSQL() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
        String answer = "Ok";
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");  
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection                          
("jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.69.207;user=sa;password=test123; database=testdb");
        //System.out.println("test");
        Statement sta = conn.createStatement();
        String Sql = "select * from qem_message";
        ResultSet rs = sta.executeQuery(Sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            //System.out.println(rs.getString("currentstatus"));
    }
    return answer;
    }}
```

After I create the webservice and invoke it from a test client, the result is:

```
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver Message: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

The same code runs perfectly fine in an independent Java class.

Comment: Your JDBC driver, the thing referred to by "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" needs to be on the classpath for wherever you are running it. When you run things from a command line vs an IDE vs inside an application, you will have different classpaths.

Comment: Thanks Trisha. I just realized what i was doing wrong. When the runtime configuration is added in the eclipse environment, it has to be added before the web service is generated. What i did wrong was i added classpath in runtime after webservice is created. Thanks for your response.